# Best way to convert LinkedHashSet to ArrayList in core Java

Tags: java

This sounds like a really dumb question, but all Google results on the first pages either:

- Use a 3rd party library
- Use an explicit loop
- Return a `List<Object>` instead of `List<YourType>`
- Answer the reversed question of converting an `ArrayList` to `Set`

What's the best way to convert a `LinkedHashSet` to an `ArrayList` while avoiding all of the above?

Comment: Did you try `new ArrayList<>(yourSet)`?

Comment: "best way" in terms of performance or in terms of simplicity/readability?

Comment: @mangusta if that matters for the answer I'd love to know.

Comment: I'm not sure if "ArrayList<>(yourSet)" would be more efficient than using third-party library. It might be as bad as looping, while third-party libs could make use of internal representation of hashset to straightforwardly convert it into arraylist in constant time. So I recommend to do a bit of research

Answer (score 3):

A simple call to `ArrayList`'s constructor should do the trick:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>(myLinkedHashSet);
```

Comment: Lol sorry thanks. That google didn't mention it though.

Answer (score 2):

```
LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.add("A");
set.add("B");
set.add("C");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
System.out.println(list); // [A, B, C]
```